# jQuery - can't access some attributes?

Tags: jquery

I am getting an `undefined` for the variables `min` and `max` in the code below:

```js
$(".filters-button-group").on("click", "input", function() {
  var min = $(this).find(".filter").attr("data-filter-price-range-min");
  var max = $(this).find(".filter").attr("data-filter-price-range-max");
  var filter_min = $(this).attr("data-filter-min");
  var filter_max = $(this).attr("data-filter-max");
  console.log(min);
  console.log(max);
  console.log(filter_min);
  console.log(filter_max);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div>
    <form>
      <p>Price Range</p>
      <ul class="filters-button-group">
        <li>
          <input data-filter="filter-price-range" data-filter-max="650" data-filter-min="300" id="price-range-300-650" type="radio">
          <label for="price-range-300-650">300 - 650</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    <span class="filter" data-filter-price-range-min="350" data-filter-price-range-max="450"></span>
  </div>
</main>
```

Is there a reason why I can access the values of the data attributes `data-filter-min` and `data-filter-max`, but not `data-filter-price-range-min` and `data-filter-price-range-max`?

Comment: your span is outside the element with filters-button-group class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to get the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), also I used [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to navigate to `.filter` element, here is a working snippet:

```js
$(".filters-button-group").on("click", "input", function() {
  var min = $(this).parents('form').next().data("filter-price-range-min");
  var max = $(this).parents('form').next().data("filter-price-range-max");
  var filter_min = $(this).data("filter-min");
  var filter_max = $(this).data("filter-max");
  console.log(min);
  console.log(max);
  console.log(filter_min);
  console.log(filter_max);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div>
    <form>
      <p>Price Range</p>
      <ul class="filters-button-group">
        <li>
          <input data-filter="filter-price-range" data-filter-max="650" data-filter-min="300" id="price-range-300-650" type="radio">
          <label for="price-range-300-650">300 - 650</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    <span class="filter" data-filter-price-range-min="350" data-filter-price-range-max="450"></span>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Using `data()` is only good if the value doesn't change, right? Subsequent calls to that method will return a cached copy of the value when it was originally accessed.

Comment: Yes, you can't rely on it to retrieve data that should not be cached.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, read [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) for more about it.

Answer (score 1):

in your code `this` is the `input` inside the `ul`
searching for the `span` with class `filter` inside the `input` will not find a result, because the `span` is outside the `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: in your current code, you need to add `.closest("form").parent()` in both lines below:

```
var min = $(this).closest("form").parent().find(".filter").attr("data-filter-price-range-min");
var max = $(this).closest("form").parent().find(".filter").attr("data-filter-price-range-max");
```

Explanation:

You are looking for a "click" event in an "input" inside ".filters-button-group". When your function is executed, `this` points to the input element, and `$(this).find(".filter")` looks for a descendant of the input with such class, but there is no descendant elements for the input in your HTML, resulting on an empty result and, consequently, `undefined` after using `.attr()`.

Note, however, that the element with the 'filter' class in a sibling of the form. Starting from the input, we are returning to the closest 'form', then its parent 'div', and finally running the `.find()` for the element with the 'filter' class.

Comment: Tested your solution. It works. Can you explain why? I've simplified the HTML, so I need to understand what's going on in order to implement the solution in my actual HTML.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Sorry, I clicked the submit before finishing the answer. I've updated it :D

Comment: It's so obvious now! Thanks.

Comment: @saulotoledo : find is not returning undefined, it returns an empty jquery result with length 0. 
else the .attr would raise an exception.

Comment: @Homungus You are right! I mean to mention the final value of the variable, this is an important fix. I will edit my answer now. @StackOverflowNewbie Please check the comment from @Homungus above. Also check the answer from @ROOT, `.parents('form').next()` is actually a nicer approach. And do not forget to set the question as answered. :D